# writing to /sys/class/gpio/export failing

Tags: gpio

I am working on a project which needs me to   configure the gpio pins and add sensors to atom board. The kernel has configured the gpio ... `CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS=y` is one of the kernel options.

I am using **fedora version 2.6.29-10**
But i am not able to write to export file in gpio folder using

```
GPIO=22  // to add pin 22 to userspace  
echo $GPIO > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

I get  the error
`bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

I also tried the same with `sudo` and `sh -c` but no use ,unless i can expose these pins to userspace i cant write any code.What am i doing wrong?
Is the problem with the kernel version or some other kernel options needs to set??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well , for the GPIO pins to be used as I have described. you need to load a module using **insmod** or **modprobe**.
After a long wait i got those modules from the manufacturers of our atom board.
The problem described above is now solved.

Comment: I have the same problem but with Zybo board of xilinx. Do you have some idea ion how to solve the problem? How to use insmod or modprobe? where to find and install them?

Comment: insmod, modprobe are standard unix commands both of which loads a kernel module. The kernel module for GPIO pins are open source and should be available with the manufacturer. I would suggest reaching out to  the community for Zybo boards.

Comment: I just need to load A module!?!  I guess which one doesn't matter, right?